# How to connect USB CD/DVD-rom to my Asus Eee transformer?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have lot of CD/DVD movie's. And i want to watch those in my Android so i bought one USB CD-DVD ROM.

But my Transformer, does not have USB input, how can i use it?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the specs](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_Pad/Eee_Pad_Transformer_TF101/#specifications), the Eee Transformer has USB ports. Android 3.1 [added USB host support](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html). The problem(s) with what you want to do is that there is no support for DVD navigation (and probably the `udf` and `cd9660` filesystems, as well) in Android. You'd be better off ripping the DVDs onto your computer and using a USB hard drive (or the Transformer's internal storage) to play them on the tablet.

Comment: There's probably no support for CD or DVD drives either :P

Comment: The Transformer only has USB ports on the keyboard dock.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for the tablet itself, but the Eee Station comes with [USB ports](http://eee.asus.com/en/eeepad/transformer/specification/), and Samsung introduced recently (Apr 2012) the world's thinnest optical drive designed for tablets.

### [Samsung introduces world’s thinnest optical drive for tablets](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Samsung-introduces-worlds-thinnest-optical-drive-for-tablets_id29492)

> The **SE-2188BB supports Android Honeycomb version 3.1 or later** and can handle a variety of media at high speeds including 24X CD-ROM, 24X CD-RW, 8X DVD±R recording, 5X DVD-RAM recording, 6X DVD+R Dual Layer recording, 6X DVD-R Dual Layer recording, 8X DVD+RW recording and 6X DVD-RW recording

[image: SE-2188BB]

*It's safe to assume that this is the type of solution you were after.*